# jQuery limit amount of iamges with same class

Tags: jquery, limit

I would like to limit the amount of images displayed by the image class. I currently have the following:

```
<img class="lImg" src="image.jpg" />
<img class="lImg" src="image.jpg" />
<img class="lImg" src="image.jpg" />
<img class="lImg" src="image.jpg" />
<img class="lImg" src="image.jpg" />
<img class="lImg" src="image.jpg" />
<img class="lImg" src="image.jpg" />
```

With jQuery how would i limit the above to say only show 5 images with the class of "lImg"

Cheers,
Dan

Comment: give parent element a height which is `5 * imgHeight` and also `overflow: hidden`. If you don't know height of the image then give height to the parent element dynamically using javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.lImg').each(function(i){
     if(i>4)
       $(this).hide();
});
```

Or just:

```
$('.lImg:gt(4)').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<img class="lImg show" src="image.jpg" />
<img class="lImg show" src="image.jpg" />
<img class="lImg show" src="image.jpg" />
<img class="lImg show" src="image.jpg" />
<img class="lImg show" src="image.jpg" />
<img class="lImg" src="image.jpg" />
<img class="lImg" src="image.jpg" />
```

CSS

```
.lImg {display:none;}
.lImg.show {display:block;}
```